# unityのスプライトを確認したい

Tags: unity2d

[[Unity] 2Dシューティングゲームを作る [チュートリアル]](https://techblog.primestructure.co.jp/2019/05/22/unity-2d%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B-%E3%83%81%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB/)

上記サイトを参考に2Dシューティングゲームを作っているのですが、HierarchyにあるPlayerというゲームオブジェクトの中にPlayer0~Player4がキチンと入っているかどうかがが分かりません。

確認する方法、もしくは入れる方法を教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

今ヒエラルキーの表示を見る限り、同列に並んでいるように見えます。
子の要素にしたいprefabをクリックして親にしたいprefabへドラッグして重ねてみてください。

Player
　↪︎Player0
　↪︎Player1
　↪︎Player2
　↪︎Player3
　↪︎Player4

このようなイメージです。

また、Player0のprefabがヒエラルキーに表示されていないようですので、
探してみて下さい。